# Как почистить локальный список удаленных меток?

Tags: git

В качестве удалённого сервера используется bitbucket.org.

```
git branch --remote
```

Так мы можем увидеть метки всех удалённых веток, которые были получены с сервера. Со временем накапливается приличное количество, так как если метка была удалена на сервере, то локально она не удаляется.

Как актуализировать локальны список удаленных меток, т.е. удалить из него метки, которых уже нет в удалённом хранилище?

---

**upd.** Я немного напутал в терминологии. Под меткой я подразумевал не `tag`, а именно названия `branch`, которого уже нет на удалённом сервере.

Comment: речь только о branch или и о tag тоже?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, *речь только о branch или и о tag тоже?* — разница между этими двумя типами указателей в данном случае, по-моему, несущественна.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я не знаю как почистить tag одной командой

Comment: вам все равно нужен git fetch --prune, это все равно дубликат того же самого)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на основании ответов к этому вопросу: [Remove local tags that are no longer on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1841341/4827341)

---

если нужно полностью синхронизировать метки с отдалённым хранилищем (все локальные метки при этом будут удалены), то с более или менее актуальными версиями программы *git*:

```
$ git tag -d $(git tag); git fetch --tags
```

или одной командой:

```
$ git fetch --prune имя-хранилища '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

---

насколько я понимаю, локально созданные (а не полученные из других хранилищ) метки никак не отмечаются (в отличие от другого типа указателей — веток (branch)), поэтому, если они вам дороги, удалять ненужные метки придётся выборочно:

```
$ git tag -d имя1 имя2 ...
```

ориентируясь на два списка:

локальных меток:

```
$ git tag
```

и меток в отдалённом хранилище:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags имя-хранилища
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я немного напутал в терминологии. Под меткой я подразумевал не tag, а именно названия branch которого уже нет на удалённом сервере.